# logical and virtual address

Tags: operating-system, memory-address

what is the exact difference between a logical and virtual address? The page table translates between virtual and physical, but then where does the logical address come in?

Answer (score 3):

Logical address is the correct term for what you have called the virtual address; you are probably getting confused with the term virtual memory.